# AWS EC2 multi-tenant no scale up: which is the simplest way to implement it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, shared-memory, multi-tenant

**the need:** I have a team of people who are not particularly tech savvy but we still want them to be able to access a `jupyter` notebook in a hosted `ec2` instance (which has got access to a variety of resources in `AWS`). Not all of the people use this instance all the time but it's reasonable to believe that that the instance will be used continuosly by one person or the other throughout the day ( and we do not have budget to scale up things on demand).

**the solution:** to use a single medium sized instance in a *multi-tenant* fashion so that basically every user could link up to it and, as more users connect, resources are re-distributed (meaning the already present users will witness reduced capacity in *RAM* and *CPU* - up to a limit as CPUs are finite in number) and, as they disconnect, the opposite happens.

**the problem & question:** I saw there are some pretty beefy/complicated infrastructure designs for this. **my question** is: what's the simplest (=least complicated/expensive to maintain solution) architecture to cater such need?

p.s. on security: all users are equal, there are not users who have got more rights than others, instance will be accessible just via a pwd, no ID management is required.

p.s. on caching sessions: after a certain period of inactivity (or you close down the browser in this case), session will be terminated on its own. no session caching needs to be employed

Comment: The simplest would be to launch one Amazon EC2 instance and have everybody access it. Resources are used by the jupyter app, not users themselves. According to the [jupyter documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html), it appears that you can use token-based authentication without needing a username/password.

Comment: that would be superbly cool. I didn't see that section on the jupyter docs!